# Добавление координат в строку .json

Tags: php, json

Здравствуйте!

Строка .json:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "options": {"strokeWidth": 3},
      "properties": {"balloonContent": "Содержимое балуна", "hintContent": "Текст подсказки"},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            55.80899899270488,
            37.77442932128906
          ],
          [
            55.800895029938275,
            37.74696350097656
          ],
          [
            55.795877445664104,
            37.709197998046875
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Пользователь вводит координаты в поле, например:
[[00.0000, 00.0000], [11.0000, 11.0000], [22.0000. 22,0000]]

Далее код php:

```
<?php

  $json = file_get_contents('data.json');
  $data = json_decode($json, true);

  $coordinates = $_POST['coordinates'];

  $arr['geometry']['coordinates'] = $coordinates;
  array_push($data['features'], $arr);

  $json = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
  file_put_contents('data.json', $json);

?>
```

После этого запись в .json выглядит так:

```
    "coordinates": "[
      [
        55.80899899270488,
        37.77442932128906
      ],
      [
        55.800895029938275,
        37.74696350097656
      ],
      [
        55.795877445664104,
        37.709197998046875
      ]
    ]"
```

А нужно, чтобы было так (без кавычек):

```
    "coordinates": [
      [
        55.80899899270488,
        37.77442932128906
      ],
      [
        55.800895029938275,
        37.74696350097656
      ],
      [
        55.795877445664104,
        37.709197998046875
      ]
    ]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?
Как исправить?
Спасибо.

Comment: У вас в $_POST['coordinates'] приходит уже json Или что?

Comment: переменная берется из <input>, координаты вводит пользователь в установленном формате [[00.0000, 00.0000], [11.0000, 11.0000], [22.0000. 22,0000]]

Comment: строку прислали, строка и добавилась. Раскодируйте `json_decode`  то что получили от пользователя, т.е. .`json_decode($coordinates)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$coordinates = json_decode ($_POST['coordinates'], true);
```

Или нужно сделать более сложный набор input-ов через html. Или через JS input сохранять в hidden поля. Атрибут name для полей в этом случае будет выглядеть как-то так:

- coordinates[0][]
- coordinates[0][]
- coordinates[1][]
- coordinates[1][]
- coordinates[2][]
- coordinates[2][]